# Vuetify CSS comes after my own CSS with Nuxt 2.0

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

In my test project https://github.com/alechance/nuxt-vuetify-lodash I'm trying to write my own CSS. However Vuetify CSS always comes after my CSS in my `<head>`, any idea how I can order my styles so my CSS comes after? I do not want to end up writing `important!`

Comment: Here: `css: ['~/assets/style/app.styl']`, add it to the array in `nuxt.config.js`

Comment: Hi, what do you mean? It's already there https://github.com/alechance/nuxt-vuetify-lodash/blob/master/nuxt.config.js#L20

Comment: Its because you are using a la carte setup, when every component will import its own css at runtime.

Comment: yes I figured this out, so there's any workaround to fix that? no options with extract text plugin maybe?