# Nuxt & Vuetify: how to control the order in which CSS files are loaded?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

In my `Nuxt/Vuetify` app I'm trying to load my custom CSS *after* `Vuetify`'s CSS, but `Vuetify`'s CSS gets loaded afterwards no matter what. I tried to reverse the order in the CSS array:

```
css: [
    '~/assets/style/main.scss',
    '~/assets/style/app.styl'
  ],
```

... and swap these around, to no avail.

The popularity of a [previous question on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53087096/vuetify-css-comes-after-my-own-css-with-nuxt-2-0) combined with its lack of answer makes me think the problem is on `Vuetify`' side and authors didn't bother to fix the issue.

But maybe that's not the right explanation and there's indeed a solution?

Comment: I believe you'd have to edit nuxt.config.js. The technique of importing vuetify css in your custom css, and disabled automatic load of it outside your custom CSS might be a solution as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like it's an open issue with Nuxt, and it's unfortunately not solved. Vuetify says they don't think it's on their side:
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify-loader/issues/23

As of Nuxt `^2.7.1`, people are having issues with inconsistent css file loading. There's a reference to it [in this issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/4204), as well as [this issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/4219).

It does seem like they are attempting to fix it, [as noted here](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/pull/5825). Unfortunately though, until this is released, I don't believe there's much you could do besides reverting to a lower version.

Answer (score 5):

As noted, this is an ongoing issue with Nuxt. However, you have a few options.

### **Option 1 The dirty but easy way...**

Remove your override CSS from the nuxt.config.js (keep Vuetify)
then add your override code a `style` block in your `default` layout.

```
<style lang="sass">
  @import assets/style/main.scss
</style>
```

The problem with this approach is you'll have to duplicate it if you add additional layouts.

### **Option #2 The better but possibly more complex way**

Create an "all" css file and import both into it. I say more complex as you may need to compile your stylus into CSS before it can be imported. However, I assume you're not changing the Vuetify styles so that likely won't be an issue.

**all.scss** (make sure to name it .scss so it gets processed)

```
@import "app.styl";
@import "main.scss";
```

Import all your CSS (in any order you want) to that one CSS file.

**nuxt.config.js**

```
css: [
    '~/assets/style/all.scss',
  ],
```

Answer (score 4):

That's still an issue in `vuetify 2.2.19`, `nuxt 2.0.0` and `@nuxt/vuetify`. The first solution could be setting `extractCss: true` in the `nuxt.config.json` (in the build section). But for me it leads to HMR bug - styles are not updated dynamically in dev environment, I had to reload the page after every style update.

The proper solution in my case is:

1. Disable `@nuxt/vuetify`, remove vuetify section entirely, remove `'@nuxtjs/vuetify` from buildModules.
2. Load styles in the correct order in styles section of `nuxt.config.js`. I don't use custom sass variables in vuetify, and for me it's like:

```
css: [
  'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css',
  '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css',
  '~/assets/styles/main.scss'
]
```

3. Even if you use custom sass variables, I would suggest to precompile vuetify based on them in a separate build step and place in static folder, because usually they don't change frequently.
4. Include vuetify manually using the following plugin:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import en from 'vuetify/lib/locale/en'
import lt from 'vuetify/lib/locale/lt'
import pl from 'vuetify/lib/locale/pl'
import colors from '~/config/colors'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default ({ app }) => {
  app.vuetify = new Vuetify({
    lang: {
      locales: { en, lt, pl },
      current: 'en'
    },
    icons: {
      iconfont: 'mdi'
    },
    theme: {
      options: {
        customProperties: true
      },
      themes: {
        light: colors
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: But with this way you loose treeshaking feature on css, right ?

Answer (score 2):

Adding in case this helps someone.   I was having trouble with a 3rd party library's css not loading properly in a NUXT project.   A dev on their support channel discovered that the problem was related to postcss.

Adding this to the nuxt.config.js fixed the issue in our case:

```
nuxt.config.js:

build: {
    postcss: false
  }
```

The item was also opened up as a NUXT bug here:
[Some CSS rules removed by PostCSS](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/10410)

Comment: I guess you will lose the ability to customize your `tailwind.config.js`

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same/similar problem.

In my case I (kinda) solved it by deleting all the css loading in the nuxt config:

```
css: [
    // ~/assets/style/app.styl,
    // ~/assets/style/custom.styl,
],
```

and added it to the plugins/vuetify.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'

import 'assets/style/app.styl'
import 'assets/style/custom.styl'

Vue.use(Vuetify)
```

Now I can override the default Vuetify theme but it takes a lot longer to recompile the code using Hot Module Replacement.

Maybe not the best way to do it but I couldn't find a better way.