# css changed after nuxt generate

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt with Vuetify.
I created a class and assigned it some padding.
The class is defined in a unscoped `<style>` in `layouts/default.vue`.
when I'm on development mode (`npm run dev`) everything looks great as I aimed for.
the class is on container element so the final html looks like
`<div class="container container--fluid my-class">`

the devtools look like that when I'm on dev mode:
[image]

so `my-class` is applied. But once I build the project (`npm run generate`) `my-class` is overridden by the `container` class rules:
[image]

I guess it is happening because of the order in which the classes combined into a single css but not sure it behaves differently for dev and built projects.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more digging it seems to be a known issue with nuxt.
It happens when declaring styles in non-scoped style tag, and using it somewhere else.

I followed these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60925793/9103301

which is basically integrating Vuetify into nuxt manually and not with `@nuxt/vuetify`.
then I could control over the order the css is loaded in `nuxt.config.js` - first vuetify and then my styling (which I moved from the layout the a `css` file).

a more basic vuetify plugin that worked for me:

```
import Vue from "vue"
import Vuetify from "vuetify"
version "^2.1.1" ,
Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default (ctx) => {
  const vuetify = new Vuetify({
    theme: {
      dark: false, // From 2.0 You have to select the theme dark or light here
    },
  })

  ctx.app.vuetify = vuetify
  ctx.$vuetify = vuetify.framework
}
```

You'll have to install icons as well, vuetify default is mdi which is installed with `npm install @mdi/font -D`

Answer (score 0):

managed to fix this by disabling tree shaking for vuetify. Change the following in nuxt.config.js:

```js
  buildModules: [
    ["@nuxtjs/vuetify", { treeShake: false }],
  ],
```