# Nuxt 3 - How to change the order of css/style in the head

Tags: vuetify.js, nuxt3, element-plus

I'm using [@element-plus/nuxt](https://github.com/element-plus/element-plus-nuxt) with the configurations same as the docs.

The problem is my custom css in nuxt config (`main.scss`) goes before the CSS of element plus. This causes my css has lower priority than element-plus's styles.

Is there any way to control the order of `<style>` tag in the `<head>`? at least bring the custom css at `main.css` to the end of the `<head>`.

Vuetify has same problem also.

[image]

Comment: Check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56665934/nuxt-vuetify-how-to-control-the-order-in-which-css-files-are-loaded

Answer (score 0):

> https://github.com/element-plus/element-plus-nuxt-starter/issues/72#issuecomment-1784165778

- If you use unocss, you can use feature [`attributify`](https://unocss.dev/presets/attributify). `p-0` It has a higher priority than `class`.
- Or you can override it by `class="p-0!"`.
- You can set `--el-main-padding: 0` for inlien style.

Of course, they may not seem like the most elegant solution.

Finally, I think you can use `div` directly for layout without having to stick to `el-main`.
The internal implementation of `el-main` is very simple and is essentially just a div.
If you have a custom situation, `div` is a better choice.